# Transform an Int "Id" to a Specific Text

Tags: sql, apache-flex, datagrid

i have a question, I want to display in a Datagrid in Flex some information of this Combobox: http://puu.sh/bU6ht/ee36ed7fd1.png

```
N/A = 0
B = 1
M = 2
NT = 3
FS = 4
ER = 5
SSE = 6
```

And is saved in the Database as int, but I want in the Datagrid display the information as String

http://puu.sh/bU6cR/3c112d85e3.png

I have a solution and is doing a Case in SQL, but i dont know if is the correct solution.

```
CASE insp._manguera
WHEN 0 THEN 'N/A' 
WHEN 1 THEN 'B' 
WHEN 2 THEN 'M' 
WHEN 3 THEN 'NT' 
WHEN 4 THEN 'FS' 
WHEN 5 THEN 'ER' 
WHEN 6 THEN 'SSE' 
END as _manguera,
```

And do that for every field in the database

Comment: Your solution with case is probably the fastest and easiest if this is just a one-off query.  If you'll need to repeat this substitution often consider making a view or table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also have a table in which you could associate the values to letters and do a join on that table.

That way, you wouldn't need to repeat that code anywhere and you could always modify the table. Good for long time use and reuse.

tell me if you need an example :)

Comment: Doing then an INNER JOIN with the other table right?, hmm, i didnt think in that, i'll try:)

Comment: That could solve your problem. Of course, when you will select one of your table, you won't see the ''text'', to see the text, you'll really need to do one of those 2 things:
1- select with a join or 2- create a view and select from it

Comment: Let's say you have table1 from which you want to retreive the data. You can do : Select table1.column1, table1.column2, table2.letters from table1 left join table2 on table1.values = table2.values;

in table2, youd have a column named values and a column named letters